# How can I reach Muiderslot castle from Amsterdam Central?

Tags: budget, public-transport, amsterdam, architecture

I'm looking for the cheapest transport option to reach the Muiderslot castle, from Amsterdam Central. Muiden is a good city to stay/sleep? I don't know if it's a good option stay in Muiden (to be near Muiden Castle) and also visit Amsterdam Centre.

Comment: It's a bus company? Do you know how much I'll spend?

Comment: Although not the cheapest, I really recommend renting a bicycle.  It's a great way to explore Amsterdam, Muiden, and the countryside in-between.  And it's not too far.

Comment: I loved the idea gerrit. Do you know where is the cheapest place to rent a bike? (and how much)

Comment: Almost all bigger and many small railway stations have a bicycle parking that also rents out bikes. I find a daily rental fee of €6.50 but the site did not contain a date. Other bicycle rent places know they have to compete with the very cheap station bikes and generally offer bikes under €10 for the basic bikes, sometimes they do better the station rental bike. Just search online with 'bicycle rent' or 'fiets huur'  and your location will find you a near one. If in the Netherlands for a longer time, check out the OV fiets. (Takes registering.)

Answer (score 6):

Just did this today, by bike, from Amsterdam City Center.

Go to the Flevopark on Amsterdam's impeccable bike lanes, then take the scenic bridge (Nesciobrug) and pedal for a few kms, mostly right along the river, in a park with bunnies (Diemerzeedijk / Waterkeringpad).

You'll cross farms, sheep, friendly people. Muiden itself has a few nice cafes and is sailing oriented. The castle itself is beautiful and smallish, and they close at 4:30pm, so try to get in at least an hour before that. Don't miss the garden outside.

Also right nearby is an old fort (Westbatterij) with cannons, behind which there's a very small and cozy beach, you can swim and enjoy.

This is the route: [Centraal to Muiderslot by bike](https://www.google.nl/maps/dir/Amsterdam+Centraal,+Stationsplein,+1012+AB+Amsterdam/Muiderslot,+Herengracht+1,+1398+AA+Muiden/@52.355631,4.9465314,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c609b70dd81623:0xcae71b8d3adfd142!2m2!1d4.900272!2d52.3791283!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c60dff27867055:0x7bb6726706837ea2!2m2!1d5.0714226!2d52.3343272!3e1)

Answer (score 4):

It takes about 50 minutes to get there and you have to change from subway to bus and then walk for a quarter of an hour. This wil cost you EUR 4.81 one way.

Muiden is too small a place to spend more than a couple of hours, so you'll probably want to return to Amsterdam.

Hiring a bicycle will cost you about 8 EURO. See http://www.amsterdam.info/transport/bike-rentals/ The bike ride will take about as much time as public transport.

Comment: You might want to add a link to the bus itinerary, for completeness sake. ;)

Comment: Small places are often great to stay, especially if you do not like staying in a city and seeing a small place before the tourist come in and after they have left can be a great experience.